# Ionic 4 Loading Controller continues after dismissing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 and the Loading Controller.

```
async presentLoading() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'wait. . .'
    });
    return await loading.present();
}
```

Works great. But now I want to dismiss the loader programatically.

```
this.loadingCtrl.dismiss().then(a => console.log('dismissed'));
```

Even though I see 'dismissed' on my console (logging worked) the loading overlay continues. Any idea what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You not dismissing the actual loader that is displayed. You have to dismiss it with `loading` variable like below :

```js
loading.dismiss().then(a => console.log('dismissed'));
```

Notice that I have used variable `loading` that you have declared for current loader.

Answer (score 0):

```
 If you want to dismiss programmatically use this in your service. 



export class LoaderService {
 private isLoading = false;
 constructor(private loadingController: LoadingController) {
  }

  async presentLoading() {
    // issue generated! so we used Boolean value to set loader dismissed call 
         firstly so we used this logic
    this.isLoading = true;
    let loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    message: 'Please Wait',
    spinner: 'bubbles'
  }).then((res) => {
      res.present();
      if (!this.isLoading) {
        // res.dismiss().then(()=> console.log('abort presenting'));
        this.loadingController.dismiss().then(() => 
console.log('Dismissed'));
     }
    });
    return loading;
  }
```

async hideLoading() {
    this.isLoading = false;
    return await this.loadingController.dismiss().then(() => console.log('Dismissed'));
   }
}

Comment: doesnt work.. donnt know why ionci added async and promise based loader everyehwere